# Error trying to pull the first field value from each row

Tags: vba, ms-access

AMTSelect is a declared variable variant type for the Getrows array

rCount is an integer

I'm trying to pull the first field value from each row but I keep getting an error saying that the subscript is out of range. The error happens in the for loop.

Code is below:

```
If Contractnum <> "" Then
    CNTRecords = "Select Count(*) from [Manual_AINs] WHERE [Manual_AINs].[Contract_Number]= '" & Contractnum & "';"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(CNTRecords)
    rCount = rs.Fields(0)
    Set rs = Nothing

        If rCount > 1 Then
            qAMT = "Select [Dollar Amount] from [Manual_AINs] WHERE ((([Manual_AINs].[Contract_Number])='" & Contractnum & "'));"
            Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qAMT)
            AMTSelect = rs.GetRows
            AMTSelectString = "Choose appropriate dollar amount of AIN from the selection below:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10)


            For i = 1 To rCount
                AMTSelectString = AMTSelectString & i & ".)  " & Format(AMTSelect(0, (i - 1)), "$#,##0.00") & Chr(10)
            Next i
```

Comment: It's in the For loop. Beginning at the AMTSelectstring yea I think some of it got deleted when I copied it but the AMTSelect is a variable.  Essentially AMTSelect = rs.GetRows

Comment: Could you explain `AMTSelect(0, (i - 1))` in the last line? Do you want to access to the `i - 1`th row in array `AMTSelect`?

Comment: Yes,  I'm not sure how nany rows it would return but I have the count of the number of rows it would return from i so I'm trying to get the first field value  of every row that would have returned if that makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't the expression `AMTSelect(i - 1)` be better? So the statement becomes `AMTSelectString = AMTSelectString & i & ".)  " & Format(AMTSelect(i - 1), "$#,##0.00") & Chr(10)`. Can you try it?

Comment: I still get the subscript out of range. I guess I'm doing something wrong with the array but I'm trying to get like the GetRows array (0,0), (0,1) etc I need the values from the first field for each row. I thought I types it right but I keep getting that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't requesting any rows with `.GetRows` - this is basically just calling `.GetRows(0)`, which won't return *any* rows into your Recordset.

Change this line...

```
AMTSelect = rs.GetRows
```

...to:

```
AMTSelect = rs.GetRows(rCount)
```

That said, since you are apparently trying to use every line in the Recordset, this is much simpler:

```
If Contractnum <> "" Then
    qAMT = "Select [Dollar_Amount] from [Manual_AINs] WHERE [Manual_AINs].[Contract_Number]='" & Contractnum & "';"
    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qAMT)
        If Not .EOF Then .MoveFirst
        AMTSelectString = "Choose appropriate dollar amount of AIN from the selection below:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
        Dim i As Long
        Do While Not .EOF
            i = i + 1
            AMTSelectString = AMTSelectString & i & ".)  " & Format$(.Fields(0), "$#,##0.00") & Chr(10)
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End If
```

Comment: I marked  the answer but I'm curious to know outside if the fact that it wasn't pulling any rows from bit having the rCount why wasnt it working?

Comment: @DanielBell - If you don't specify a number of rows for `.GetRows` to return it defaults to 0.